# Getting MS-DOS SMARTDrive version from interrupt call 2F/AX=4A10h/BX=0000h

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm trying to write an assembly procedure to get the SMARTDrive version on a given system.  The code to detect if SMARTDrive is loaded works correctly, but I can't seem to get the version from the Base Pointer (BP) register.  My compiler, Digital Mars, doesn't seem to support the BP register in the REGS structure of DOS.H, so I can't use regs.x.bp.

I'm using Ralph Brown's Interrupt List as a guide, located here: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-4822.htm

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
.MODEL Large, C
PUBLIC _get_smartdrive_version

_get_smartdrive_version proc
    cli
    mov ax, 4A10h
    mov bx, 0000h
    mov cx, 0EBABh
    int 2Fh
    cmp ax, 0BABEh          ; verify SMARTDrive signature
    jne no_smartdrv
    xor ax, ax              ; probably not needed
    mov ax, dword ptr [bp]  ; (note also tried without dword ptr, and with es:[bp])
    jmp done
no_smartdrv:
    mov ax, 0
done:
    sti
    ret
_get_smartdrive_version endp

end
```

This **should** return the version in the AX register, but when I run this code it hangs my system.  I'm not really sure how to access the data in the BP register without locking up the system.  Does anyone else have experience on how to do this correctly?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dword ptr` or square brackets mean memory access. According to your link you should **not** use `bp` as an address. Just `mov ax, bp`. (Your function should probably preserve the prior `bp` using `push` and `pop`, too.)

Comment: Good point.  I'll add `push bp` and `pop bp` into my code.  Also, thanks for the explanation on the use of `dword ptr` and square brackets.  I did try just using `mov ax, bp` but it seemed to hang as well.  I'll try that again just to verify the result.

Comment: The function you're calling is listed as overwriting a lot of registers, possibly even `ds` and `es`. You have to preserve all callee-save registers. You need to know the calling convention for your compiler.

Comment: `mov ax, dword ptr [bp]` is trying to load 4 bytes from memory into a 2-byte AX.  That shouldn't assemble.  Check the machine code to see what it's actually disassembling as.

Comment: It looks like `mov ax, bp` worked!  I swear I tried that already... but come to think of it I may have had the two reversed as `mov bp, ax`, which is obviously wrong. @ecm are you saying I should add a `push ax` and `push bx` as well as `push ds` and `push es`?

Comment: You need to look up your compiler's calling convention. You certainly mustn't preserve `ax` as that would defeat using `ax` as a return value register. But `di`, `si`, `ds`, `es` and perhaps `bx` should be preserved probably. Look at the description you linked! If in doubt, better choose to preserve if you don't know whether you need to. Except `ax` as noted.

Answer (score 1):

Switching the line:

```
mov ax, dword ptr [bp]
```

To:

```
mov ax, bp
```

Worked.